Potential Free contact for VFD using Relay
I am developing a VFD and I have seen that many VFD give potential free contacts. However I am not entirely sure what is the use of these contacts. I have been told it is for Emergency stop switch but I am still unable to understand this. Can someone explain me this?
Please see the image from VFD manual
My question is suppose a Fault is detected, relay will change its state from NO to NC or vice versa. But what if Emergency switch (NC) is pressed ? How will VFD know what happened?

The manual for any commercial VFD will explain what status the relay contacts can be configured to show (fault, zero-speed, over-current, etc.) and give wiring examples. Have a look at one and modify your question if you are still uncertain.

Manual states relay output.


But what if Emergency switch (NC) is pressed ? How will VFD know what happened?

For industrial control systems complying with international safety standards there are two common ways to stop the motion safely:

Give a stop command to the drive and disconnect the motor using one or two (for redundancy) safety contactors. The drive doesn't know what class of stop is given - normal or emergency.
Many drives now have dual safe-torque inputs, typically using 24 V logic. To enable the drive both must be powered on within 0.5 s of each other (or similar). Loss of one or both safe-torque inputs will emergency stop the drive in such a way that the output switching devices can't commutate and the motor can't run. In this case the drive knows the reason for the stop.


These relays can be used for primitive fault signaling in basic applications.
There are often two relays, alarm and fault. Alarm is often reprogrammable.
Many industrial devices in a machine have such contacts, and these are then all wired in series creating a safety-chain. Example are circuit breakers, phase sequence detectors, temperature sensors or even power supplies.
All relays must be energized (NO contact closed) for the machine to function. If any of the relays is not, there is a general fault and the machine will not operate. It's a very simple way to ensure faults will turn off the machine regardless of functioning software.
Detailed fault signaling can be done with additional IO or digital communication (eg: RS-485).
Or if you like your service engineers, the on board HMI display with human readable text.
(if you hate them please use the budget vfd with 7-segment hmi and incomprehensible manual)

Emergency stops are a complicated subject highly dependent on the machine itself. I'd recommend investigating the relevant standards of the application area you are targeting. Start with IEC 60204-1.

This relay output can be configured for a variety of functions.  You choose the function by setting parameter A055 in the VFD.
To be clear, this is one output relay, with two contacts: one Normally-Open, the other Normally-Closed.
As others have mentioned, there are a few common uses for an output like this.  One is to set it to trip when the drive is faulted.  You could wire it into a PLC input so you would know when the drive is faulted.
I don't know which VFD you are using, but another common use for this, related to Emergency Stop, is Safety Feedback Monitoring.  If your VFD has a Safe-Torque-Off feature, you can configure this output to act as a feedback output for the STO.  It would then be wired back to your safety controller, and the safety controller would be able to detect if there is a fault in your STO function.
